# Git merge and warning message

Tags: git

I am very new to `git` and already met a lot of bad situations before such as losing commits so a bit scared to do this process myself so, I had two different branches and I merged one of them with `master branch` and when I tried to merge, it says

> This merge has conflicts that must be resolved before it can be committed. To manually merge these changes into master run the following commands:

```
git checkout master
git merge remotes/origin/edit
```

Does it mean, I need to enter the given commands and `git push origin master` again to store the latest version of the `master branch` on my remote repo.

Comment: What command did you run to generate this error message?

Comment: I have merged manually on my remote repo

Comment: then I did `git pull origin master` on my local repo

Comment: According to your description, 1st you have to pull from master branch (`git pull origin master`), 2nd resolved conflict, 3rd commit and push to master branch (`git push origin master`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+resolve+conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have followed the following steps:

1. Checked out master
2. Merged branch-A to master
3. You got conflicts.

If it is the case, then go to the files with conflicts and fix it.

The conflicts will be shown between a head and a tail.

```
<<<<<<<HEAD
Your local code
=======
Code that is updated from the merge or pull
>>>>>>>id
```

You could retain the code whichever is required and remove the rest.

Then run the following commands

```
git add --all
git commit -am "Conflict Fix Message"
git push
```